# Does a page created with hook_menu have a nodeid?

Tags: nodes, routes

I created a page implementing the hook_menu, and I want to apply a theme for only this specific page. I know that I need to use something like `page--node--nodeid.tpl.php`, my question is does a page created implementing the `hook_menu()` have the nodeid, and if the answer is yes, how can I figure it out ?

Comment: What do you mean by _does a page created implementing the hook_menu() have the nodeid_? Yes, the node page is implemented in `hook_menu()`, and yes the node ID is available to that page. Is that what you need to know?

Comment: Yup, so how can I get it so I can edit the theme of that page please ?

Comment: See the dupe - template suggestions for specific nodes also exist

Comment: `does a page created implementing the hook_menu() have the nodeid` : No, a page you created yourself through hook_menu is not a node, so it does not have a node ID. You can't use a node template file to customize this page.

Comment: You can check this link to get a template on your custom page : http://drupal.aspcode.net/ppst/63547274810018958071136/change-pagetpl-template-inside-a-hookmenu-callback